# Pageview isn't showing up under pages

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to set up a virtual page view using Google Tag Manager that will register a pageview in GA4. The tag is based on a button click. GTM shows the tag firing but the pageview isn't showing up under pages. I want to be able to use the virtual pageview in a funnel. I've attached the tag configuration. Any help would be much appreciated as I'm unable to find any comprehensive documentation or examples of what I'm trying to do.

[image: screenshot of virtual pageview tag configuration]

Answer (score 0):

That tag will only issue page_view on history changes. If you want to force a page view, you still can, but you have to use a GA4 event tag like so:[image]

Configuration tag in my case

It's considered a good practice to suppress default pageviews that the config tag offers to fire for you and rely on the dataLayer events being pushed by your front-end.

Comment: Looks like that worked. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!